# share tex with binding text xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I can't share a binding name here is the code

I can't call the binding name, I just share a string, please could someone help me on how to call the binding name?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="XF_ListViewDetails_MVVM.Views.ListDetailPage"
             Title="Lanches"
             BackgroundColor="Maroon">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Lanches}" 
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  SeparatorVisibility="None"
                  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Label  x:Name="Nome666"
                                                       Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding Nome}"
                                   FontSize="Medium"
                                   TextColor="White"
                                   VerticalOptions="End"/>
                          

                            <Button x:Name="Button666"
                                Text="Compartilhar Texto"
                                    Clicked="ButtonClicked"
                                    />

                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

here is the code in cs

```
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using XF_ListViewDetails_MVVM.ViewModels;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace XF_ListViewDetails_MVVM.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ListDetailPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ListDetailPage(string Nome, string Ingredientes, string fonte)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new ListDetailPageViewModel();
        }

          async void ButtonClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
        {

         await CompartilharTexto(Nome666.Text);


        }

             public async Task CompartilharTexto(string texto)

       {

          await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareTextRequest

       {
        Text = texto,
        Title = "Compartilhando Texto"


         });
 

    }
        }}
```

the code does not share I need to know how to call the binding name on the home page, it does not run in the model only on the home page

Comment: what is "Home" page?  None of the code you posted is named "Home".   It is very unclear exactly what the problem you are having is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the value of the selected row from the binding context

```
async void ButtonClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
{
   var btn = (Button)sender;  
   var item = (YourClassNameGoesHere)btn.BindingContext;
   await CompartilharTexto(item.Nome);
}
```

Comment: stayed the same don't call the Name binding

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: item.Nome, Nome is red

Comment: Did you cast the BindingContext to ListModel?

Comment: yes cast in the BindingContext to ListModel

Comment: And ListModel has a property “Nome”?

Comment: yes have, why?...........

Comment: Please stop posting additional code as answers.  I can’t help you if you can’t explain what the problem is.  What does “Nome is red” mean?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression Status
Error CS1061 'ListDetailPageViewModel' does not contain a definition for "Nome" and could not find any extension method "Nome" that accepts a first argument of type 'ListDetailPageViewModel' (are you forgetting to use a directive or an assembly reference? )

Comment: this line should be `var item = (ListModel)btn.BindingContext;`.  Is that what you have?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ListDetailPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ListModel> Lanches { get; set; }
    public ListDetailPageViewModel()
    {
        Lanches = new ObservableCollection<ListModel>();

        Lanches.Add(new ListModel
        {
            Nome = "Cheese Burger Completo",
        });

        Lanches.Add(new ListModel
        {
            Nome = "Cheese Salada Completo",
        });

        Lanches.Add(new ListModel
        {
            Nome = "Cheese Burger com Ovo ",
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: if you are adding additional information to your question, please use the [Edit] function

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression Status
Error CS1061 'ListDetailPageViewModel' does not contain a definition for "Nome" and could not find any extension method "Nome" that accepts a first argument of type 'ListDetailPageViewModel' (are you forgetting to use a directive or an assembly reference? )

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace XF_ListViewDetails_MVVM.Models
{
    public class ListModel
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        
        public string Detalhe { get; set; }
        public string Imagem { get; set; }
        public string Ingredientes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.